# Is it better to use fwrite() or move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, file-upload, coding-style

It's more of a coding standards question this one. Which one is, if I can call it "better" to use in file upload handler scripts?

I know that `fwrite()` and it's accompanying methods for reading and writing can do it in chunks but using `move_uploaded_file()` is much more elegant and shorter code.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `move_uploaded_file()`. It does extra checks to ensure the user is not into any funny business. Also, using `fread()` and `fwrite()` **copies** the file, instead of **moving** it, which is a few orders of magnitude more costly than just moving it (which basically just changes it's **name**, given that the source and the destination are on the same partition).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please upvote the question I think it can help a lot of developers in deciding how to write a upload handler script. =D

Answer (score 4):

You should use `fwrite()` for writing to files and `move_uploaded_file()` for uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` is preferable. You can read/write files with `fwrite` and `fread`, but don't forget to check if the file is uploaded by using `is_uploaded_file`